# Explanatory and Etymological dictionary of the Latin Language

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, etymology, meaning, dictionary

With the term explanatory I am translating [ερμηνευτικό](http://www.greek-language.gr/greekLang/modern_greek/tools/lexica/triantafyllides/search.html?lq=%22%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%BC%CE%B7%CE%BD%CE%B5%CF%85%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CF%8C%CF%82%20-%CE%AE%20-%CF%8C%22&dq=). A dictionary which defines words comprehensively and clearly.

If one considers Oxford University to be the authority on the English language which university is the authority on the Latin language? Oxford English dictionary is Oxford University Press' "[best](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51633958#51633958)" explanatory english dictionary(or so I have been told in the hyperlink I provided; I bought Oxford Advanced Learners' Dictionary and Cambridge Advanced Learners' Dictionary 10 years ago but I use Lexico or Cambridge online dictionaries) which dictionary is that(the authority on the Latin language) university's best dictionary?

Comment: Take a look at this question: [Which online Latin dictionaries should I use and why?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79) You can find a long list of possible online Latin dictionaries there. Does that answer your question, or do you want something more specific? There is no unique meaning of "best" or "most authoritative", so you might want to be somewhat more specific.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I indeed did not specify which quality(or set of qualities) should we optimize. A utility/cost function. But I stated an analogy. OED. What dictionary is most "oxonian". Whichever, Whatever, Regardless of the qualities that Oxford English Dictonary possesses subjectively for each person.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing to a Latin dictionary along the lines of the OED that I know of is the *Thesaurus Linguae Latinae.* But it is not finished yet, and not likely to be finished for quite some time.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thesaurus_Linguae_Latinae), it won't be completed until 2050. They aren't kidding when they call it a monumental dictionary.